# Resistors in high frequency

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, frequency, electronics, electrical-engineering

My question is this:
Can we use ordinary resistors like those we use in labs(1.2K ohm), in high frequency (like 4GHz)?

Comment: you mean the ones with color stripes and leads? it depends on what you mean by "can". anyhow, just be aware that the leads will be small radiating antennas, and the actual effective resistance will depend on the orientation and neighboring circuit elements, so you will have very little idea what your "resistor" is really doing.

Comment: There is no other information. like can a simple resistor of any kind (1.2K ohm is important) handle this frequency? And what do you mean by your last paragraph? Thank you.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Aaah, didn't know that one. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a physical perspective, while it is possible to use axial-lead resistors (the "peanut" type), you will have poorer performance as you increase the frequency due to the skin effect.

For RF-type circuits, printed circuit boards (PCB) are the preferred device as more compact designs can be reached, and most importantly related to resistors specifically, that axial-lead resistors need to be soldered through the PCB.

[image: Resistor types]

Compared to film resistors, you can see how the area for the film resistor is much smaller, therefore the potential locations for electromagnetic leakage are reduced.

axial-lead components can be used up to a few hundred megahertz (See https://www.onetransistor.eu/2015/12/hf-vhf-antenna-amplifier-without-coils.html for a reference)

I call "electromagnetic leakage" but if you want to be more precise and rigorous, what happens is that parasitic inductance, capacitance and resistance increase with the frequency.

[image]

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-031-14186-7_11

Finally, the manufacturing precision of film components is much higher (the tolerance for axial-lead resistors is 5-10% as far as I remember, while film resistors have much more reduced tolerances as you can very precisely control the resistance of a film at a lower production price).

I tried looking for simulations of axial-lead resistors Vs. film resistors, but I could not find anything readily available, so I guess that there were many other advantages that were discovered prior to readily-available EM simulators making such simulations not as important.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely yes. Only low resistance resistors consist of wire, that can have excess inductance, that would be important at GHz frequencies. But that would be below 10 Ohms. Anything above that is likely safe to use. Especially if you dont care much about exact resistance - resistor might appear as having larger resistance because of dielectric loss.

Comment: You can get wire wound resistors up to at least 560k (first distributor I looked at, could go higher).